# Windows phone background agent ShellTile can't be added

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile, background-agents

I'm using this code to push notifications:

```
        protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
            //TODO: Add code to perform your task in background

            string toastMessage = "Periodic task running.";

            ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
            toast.Title = "Background Agent Sample";
            toast.Content = toastMessage;
            toast.Show();




#if DEBUG
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(
                task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
#endif


            NotifyComplete();
        }
```

The shell toast works great. The problem is that when I use

```
ShellTile tile = Shelltilve.ActiveTiles.First();
```

I can't find the First Method.

I'm using a Windows Phone 8 if that helps. I searched and I found that it works, but haven't been able to do it with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your code file?

Comment: i just added it, it works :P 
i was using the phone.shell :D
thank you.